# How to compile bootstrap scss to only contain the extended classes

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, mixins

How do I compile my custom bootstrap SCSS file into a CSS file which contains only the class I created in my custom file?

For instance. I'm trying to remove the the extra CSS classes added to my HTML.

Instead of writing the following HTML:

```
<h4 class="border-bottom p-2 mb-4">
    Blah Blah
    <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill float-right">100</span>
</h4>
```

I was trying to write (removing all the class attributes):

```
<h4>
    Blah Blah
    <span>100</span>
</h4>
```

For this I created a custom.scss file with the following content:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/borders";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/spacing";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/float";
@import "bootstrap/scss/badge";

h4 {
    @extend .border-bottom;
    @extend .p-2;
    @extend .mb-4;
}

h4 span {
    @extend .float-right;
    @extend .badge;
    @extend .badge-pill;
    @extend .badge-secondary;
}
```

The compiled CSS file contains 1000+ lines of CSS? Why?

It contains stuff like "badge-dark", all the padding and margin stuff etc., which I don't want to use nor they needed. How to get rid of it? I only need a CSS containing the relevant CSS instructions I wrote in my custom.scss file.

The result I thought, should look something like this:

```
h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
  padding: 0.5rem !important;
}

h4 span {
  float: right !important;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  h4 span:empty {
    display: none;
  }

  padding-right: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;

  h4 span[href]:hover, h4 span[href]:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #545b62;
  }
}
```

But it isn't.

**Edit:**

If I change my custom.scss to something like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$theme-colors: (
    "secondary":  $secondary,
);

h4 {
    border-bottom: $border-width solid $border-color;
    padding: map_get($spacers, 2);
    margin-bottom: map_get($spacers, 4);
}

@import "bootstrap/scss/badge";

h4 span {
    @include float-right;
    @extend .badge;
    @extend .badge-pill;
    @extend .badge-secondary;
}
```

The resulting CSS will mostly contain the required styles. But I thought it woud be possible to rely on the bootstrap classes instead of searching through the bootstrap SCSS and picking up the required stuff and merge it somehow into my custom.scss. I thought it would be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, but you are extending classes not placeholders. This is the big difference, here.

Example extending classes (your case)

```
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

h4{
  @extend .border-bottom;
}
```

The result is a group of CSS rules 'cause also `.border-bottom` class exists in your CSS:

```
.border-bottom, h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}
```

With `placeholder`, instead, the things are different:

```
%border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

h4{
  @extend %border-bottom;
}
```

The result is what you expect, I think:

```
h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}
```

I found here a very good article about this difference: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors

So, when you import all those Boostrap4 files, Scss creates all those `.class` rules (for this you have 1000+ code lines) that you use to extend.

Then, when you write for example this:

```
h4 {
    @include float-right;
    @extend .badge;
    @extend .badge-pill;
    @extend .badge-secondary;
}
```

Your result will be:

```
h4 {
  float: right !important; /* your @include */
}
```

But also:

```
.badge-secondary, h4 {...}

.badge-pill, h4 {...}

.btn .badge, .btn h4 {...}

.badge:empty, h4:empty {...}

.badge-secondary[href]:hover, h4[href]:hover, .badge-secondary[href]:focus, h4[href]:focus {...}

.badge, h4 {...}
```

Comment: Ok. Seems not possible with Bootstrap4 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18805). I will take a look at https://github.com/csscoderRU/bootstrap-silent-grid instead.

Comment: I think so too. Good luck with your project! :-)